# Relativistic conical pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I came across this problem while going through old exams of my Physics department:

> A pendulum with mass $m$ is swinging on the $xy$ plane at high velocity $v = 10^7\ ms^{-1}$, performing a circular motion with radius $r = 1\ m$. The mass is emitting light beams in radial direction at any point in time.

One of the questions is:

> Another observer is moving towards the pendulum from the positive $x$-axis at velocity $v_B = 300\ ms^{-1}$. What will the angular frequency $\omega\ '$ be, as measured by the observer in its frame of reference?

I know that the emitting light has to be part of the solution, since a light beam is emitted in the direction of the moving observer at regular intervalls $T$, where $T$ is the period of the circular motion as measured in the frame of reference $S$, which is at rest with the suspension point of the pendulum.

How ever I can't figure out the time intervall between the reception of two successive beams by the moving observer, as measured in the frame of reference $S$. Any hints?

Comment: Hi Ciambello ! Can you give us the brief workings of your previous attempts at figuring the time interval ? In case you haven't gone through it already, please read the site [guidelines](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in terms of events. In the frame $S$, we can define the period as the time interval between events $(R,0,0)$ and $(-R,0,T)$ (we are assuming counter clockwise rotation, and choosing the x-y origin to be at the center of the circle, and choosing $t=0$ to be when the pendulum makes a zero angle with the x-axis).

Now for the other observer $S'$ you should use the formulas 
\begin{align}
t'&=\gamma \left( t - vx/c^2\right) \\
x'&=\gamma \left( x - vt \right)
\end{align}

To obtain the new events $(x_1',y_1',t_1')$ and $(x_2',y_2',t_2')$, and the period will be $t_2' - t_1'$.